# Not getting response on simulator when i call web service using java script

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova

Hi i am using phone gap technology for blackberry development . i want to call soap based  xml .when i run html page on internet explore web service response will come  but when i run in simulator or device no response will come.Please help.thanks in advance .i used java script.

```js
/* 
 Javascript "SOAP Client" library

 @version: 2.1 - 2006.09.08
 @author: Matteo Casati - http://www.guru4.net/

*/    
var arr = new Array();
var arrayIndex;
arrayIndex = 0;

function SOAPClientParameters()
{
    var _pl = new Array();
    this.add = function(name, value) 
    {
        _pl[name] = value; 
        return this; 
    }
    this.toXml = function()
    {

        var xml = "";
        for(var p in _pl)
            xml += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(_pl[p]) + "</" + p + ">";
        return xml; 
    }
}

SOAPClientParameters._serialize = function(o)
{
    var s = "";
    switch(typeof(o))
    {
        case "string":
            s += o.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"); break;
        case "number":
        case "boolean":
            s += o.toString(); break;
        case "object":
            // Date
            if(o.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Date()") > -1)
            {

                var year = o.getFullYear().toString();
                var month = (o.getMonth() + 1).toString(); month = (month.length == 1) ? "0" + month : month;
                var date = o.getDate().toString(); date = (date.length == 1) ? "0" + date : date;
                var hours = o.getHours().toString(); hours = (hours.length == 1) ? "0" + hours : hours;
                var minutes = o.getMinutes().toString(); minutes = (minutes.length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                var seconds = o.getSeconds().toString(); seconds = (seconds.length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                var milliseconds = o.getMilliseconds().toString();
                var tzminutes = Math.abs(o.getTimezoneOffset());
                var tzhours = 0;
                while(tzminutes >= 60)
                {
                    tzhours++;
                    tzminutes -= 60;
                }
                tzminutes = (tzminutes.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + tzminutes.toString() : tzminutes.toString();
                tzhours = (tzhours.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + tzhours.toString() : tzhours.toString();
                var timezone = ((o.getTimezoneOffset() < 0) ? "+" : "-") + tzhours + ":" + tzminutes;
                s += year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds + timezone;
            }
            // Array
            else if(o.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Array()") > -1)
            {
                for(var p in o)
                {
                    if(!isNaN(p))   // linear array
                    {
                        (/function\s+(\w*)\s*\(/ig).exec(o[p].constructor.toString());
                        var type = RegExp.$1;
                        switch(type)
                        {
                            case "":
                                type = typeof(o[p]);
                            case "String":
                                type = "string"; break;
                            case "Number":
                                type = "int"; break;
                            case "Boolean":
                                type = "bool"; break;
                            case "Date":
                                type = "DateTime"; break;
                        }
                        s += "<" + type + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p]) + "</" + type + ">"
                    }
                    else    // associative array
                        s += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p]) + "</" + p + ">"
                }
            }
            // Object or custom function
            else
                for(var p in o)
                    s += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p]) + "</" + p + ">";
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(500, "SOAPClientParameters: type '" + typeof(o) + "' is not supported");
    }
    return s;
}

function SOAPClient() {}

SOAPClient.invoke = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback)
{
    if(async)
        SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
    else
        return SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
}

// private: wsdl cache
SOAPClient_cacheWsdl = new Array();

// private: invoke async
SOAPClient._loadWsdl = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback)
{
    // load from cache?
    var wsdl = SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url];
    if(wsdl + "" != "" && wsdl + "" != "undefined")
        return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl);
    // get wsdl
    var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
    if(async) 
    {
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    if (!async)
        return SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback, xmlHttp);
}
SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback, req)
{
    var wsdl = req.responseXML;
    SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url] = wsdl;   // save a copy in cache
    return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl);
}
SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback, wsdl)
{
    // get namespace
    var ns = (wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"] + "" == "undefined") ? wsdl.documentElement.attributes.getNamedItem("targetNamespace").nodeValue : wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"].value;
alert(ns);
// build SOAP request
    var sr = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<soap:Envelope " +
                "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +
                "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                "<soap:Body>" +
                "<" + method + " xmlns=\"" + ns + "\">" +
                parameters.toXml() +
                "</" + method + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    // send request
    var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, async);
    var soapaction = ((ns.lastIndexOf("/") != ns.length - 1) ? ns + "/" : ns) + method;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    if(async) 
    {
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
                SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl, xmlHttp);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(sr);
    if (!async)
        return SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl, xmlHttp);
}

SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest = function(method, async, callback, wsdl, req) 
{

    var o = null;
    var nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, method + "Response");
alert("ND " +nd);
    if(nd.length == 0)
    {

        if(req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultcode").length > 0)
        {

            if(async || callback)
                o = new Error(500, req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            else
                throw new Error(500, req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);           
        } else {

        }
    }
    else{

        o = SOAPClient._soapresult2object(nd[0], wsdl);
    }
    if(callback){









        callback(arr);
    }
    if(!async)
        return o;
}
SOAPClient._soapresult2object = function(node, wsdl)
{
    var wsdlTypes = SOAPClient._getTypesFromWsdl(wsdl);

    return SOAPClient._node2object(node, wsdlTypes);
}

SOAPClient._node2object = function(node, wsdlTypes)
{

  if(node == null)
  {
    return null;
  } 


  // text node
  if(node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4) 
    return SOAPClient._extractValue(node, wsdlTypes);

  // leaf node
  if (node.childNodes.length == 1 && (node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3 || node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 4))
     return SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[0], wsdlTypes);



  var isarray = SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.nodeName, wsdlTypes).toLowerCase().indexOf("arrayof") != -1;
  // object node
  if(!isarray)
 {

     var obj = null;
     if(node.hasChildNodes())
     {
          obj = new Object();

          for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length ; i++)
         {    

    var p = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);


                  if((node.childNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("Return") == -1) && (node.childNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("Response") == -1))
{
      obj[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] = p; 

}

         }
        arr[arrayIndex++] = obj;
     }
     return obj;
  }
  // list node
  else
  {
      //create node ref

     var l = new Array();
     for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
       l[l.length] = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);
     return l;
  }
  return null;
}


SOAPClient._extractValue = function(node, wsdlTypes)
{

    var value = node.nodeValue;


    switch(SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.parentNode.nodeName, wsdlTypes).toLowerCase())
    {
        default:
        case "s:string":            
            return (value != null) ? value + "" : "";
        case "s:boolean":
            return value + "" == "true";
        case "s:int":
        case "s:long":
            return (value != null) ? parseInt(value + "", 10) : 0;
        case "s:double":
            return (value != null) ? parseFloat(value + "") : 0;
        case "s:datetime":
            if(value == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                value = value + "";
                value = value.substring(0, (value.lastIndexOf(".") == -1 ? value.length : value.lastIndexOf(".")));
                value = value.replace(/T/gi," ");
                value = value.replace(/-/gi,"/");
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(Date.parse(value));                                       
                return d;               
            }
    }
}
SOAPClient._getTypesFromWsdl = function(wsdl)
{
    var wsdlTypes = new Array();
    // IE
    var ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("s:element");   
    var useNamedItem = true;
    // MOZ
    if(ell.length == 0)
    {
        ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("element");      
        useNamedItem = false;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < ell.length; i++)
    {
        if(useNamedItem)
        {
            if(ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name") != null && ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("type") != null) 
                wsdlTypes[ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue] = ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("type").nodeValue;
        }   
        else
        {
            if(ell[i].attributes["name"] != null && ell[i].attributes["type"] != null)
                wsdlTypes[ell[i].attributes["name"].value] = ell[i].attributes["type"].value;
        }
    }

    return wsdlTypes;
}
SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl = function(elementname, wsdlTypes)
{
    var type = wsdlTypes[elementname] + "";
    return (type == "undefined") ? "" : type;
}
// private: utils
SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName = function(document, tagName)
{
    try
    {
        // trying to get node omitting any namespaces (latest versions of MSXML.XMLDocument)
        return document.selectNodes(".//*[local-name()=\""+ tagName +"\"]");
    }
    catch (ex) {}
    // old XML parser support
    return document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
}
// private: xmlhttp factory
SOAPClient._getXmlHttp = function() 
{
    try
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // some versions of Moz do not support the readyState property and the onreadystate event so we patch it!
            if(req.readyState == null) 
            {
                req.readyState = 1;
                req.addEventListener("load", 
                                    function() 
                                    {
                                        req.readyState = 4;
                                        if(typeof req.onreadystatechange == "function")
                                            req.onreadystatechange();
                                    },
                                    false);
            }
            return req;
        }
        if(window.ActiveXObject) 
            return new ActiveXObject(SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID());
    }
    catch (ex) {}
    throw new Error("Your browser does not support XmlHttp objects");
}
SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID = function()
{
    if(SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid)
        return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid;
    var progids = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
    var o;
    for(var i = 0; i < progids.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            o = new ActiveXObject(progids[i]);
            return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid = progids[i];
        }
        catch (ex) {};
    }
    throw new Error("Could not find an installed XML parser");
}

xmlParsingDataReturn=function(){
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a WebWorks app, you are required to whitelist any external domains you will be accessing through your app. Since this works on a computer's browser but not on an actual device or on the simulator, it may be an issue with the config file. See the [PhoneGap site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide_blackberry) for more info on whitelisting.